# Colours consistently change in Illustrator the moment I deselect an object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color, color-theory, cmyk

While working with a file I noticed that the moment I imported my Illustrator file into Photoshop it changed our company colour #ff5522 to a different orange-red variable.

Considering brand-consistency is pressed on, I tried to figure out what went wrong. Then I discovered that while working inside Illustrator CS6 the program would change the colour of any object the very moment I went and selected an other vector inside the same document. I played a bit with the colour settings hoping to stop this from happening, but nothing seems to work.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hi Dennis, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Do you have a screenshot? That might help a lot in finding out what's happening. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Thats's because you export it in CMYK and you paste/import it in RGB.
Keep in mind that both programs (illustrator and photoshop) has to be set with the same color mode.

So, go to your file in illustrator and click on "File" > "Document color mode" > "RGB Color"

Now fill your illustrator file with your color #ff5522.
Paste it on photoshop or just save it, and import it.